# Is there a library that allows me to load jQuery at the bottom of the page but still pepper my html with $(function() {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I vaguely recall someone coming up with a solution to this problem, but I can't for the life of me remember the name of the library. The basic idea is that by loading a single, small library at the top of the page, you can get the rendering speed advantage of loading your other scripts at the bottom of the page while being able to queue functions to be run at DOM ready. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Head JS](http://headjs.com/)?

> You’ve read the books and placed SCRIPT SRC tags on the bottom. Good. But can you do this?
>
> ```
> // use jQuery on the body of the page even though it is not included yet
> head.ready(function() {
>    $("#my").jquery_plugin();
> });
>
> // load jQuery whenever you wish bottom of the page
> head.js("/path/to/jquery.js");
> ```